# How do I implement a single login system for drupal and another CMS?

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, integration

I am trying to implement a login share between a Drupal site and another CMS - kayako in particular.

How do I implement a single login system for drupal and another CMS?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "login share"? Log in once and have access to everything? Use the same login and password on both sites? Something else?

Comment: I mean if a user logs in one of websites, he/she get logged in in other website as well. This process should be done on both sides. My question is regarding the Drupal's side, ie. login the user in Drupal from the other application. Using the same username/password is a plus, but am not sure that can be done easily because each application keeps user credentials in different way.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 6 supports [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) out of the box.

If kayako provides an API for user authentication, you can also implements an external authentication module for Drupal. This module will have to implements [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter/6) to edit the [user_login](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/user_login/6) and [user_login_block](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/user_login_block/6) forms and replace [user_login_authenticate_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/user_login_default_validators/6) in their `$form['#validate']` by the module's own *validation* callback that should authenticate the user.